# how can i use regex to pass this rspec test?

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I am having some trouble getting a rspec test to pass. My method has passed all the other tests for it except the last one which requires that a word/hash pair be returned if the keyword matches the argument or if the keyword has the same prefix (if a prefix is the argument). In the latter case,  If there is more than one match, then the returned hash should include them all. As is, the code that I have is returning the entire hash, so it seems that maybe the regex is not being compared? I have tried multiple ways of doing this but here are two, the first one being what I reverted back to because it has passed the most tests.

```
def find(word)
    returns = {}
    if @entries.empty? 
    @entries 
    else 
      @entries.select{|key, value| if key.scan(/word/) then @entries[key] = value  end } 
    end
  end
```

which returned the fail:

```
1) Dictionary finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)                                                          
     Failure/Error: @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}                                                              
       expected: {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person"}                                                                                             
            got: {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person", "great"=>"remarkable"} (using ==)
```

## ------------------------------------------------

My next attempt:

```
def find(word_or_prefix)
    returns = {}
    if @entries.empty? 
      return @entries 
    else 
      @entries.select{|key, value| if (/word_or_prefix/ =~ key) then returns <<  @entries[key] = value  end } 
    end
    returns
  end
```

returned the fail:

```
1) Dictionary finds an entry                                                                                                                                    
     Failure/Error: @d.find('fish').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}                                                                                        
       expected: {"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}                                                                                                        
            got: {} (using ==)                                                                                                                                    
       Diff:                                                                                                                                                      
       @@ -1,2 +1 @@                                                                                                                                              
       -"fish" => "aquatic animal",
```

What is the best way to use a regex to get this code to pass? And why isn't my current code passing?

While there are a total of 4 test blocks concerning the find method, is the one (the 4th) that I am having the troubles with:

```
 it 'finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('fiend' => 'wicked person')
    @d.add('great' => 'remarkable')
    @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}
  end
```

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood what [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) does. `@entries.select { |key, value| <expression>  }` returns a hash containing all key-value pairs in `@entries` for which `<expression>` evaluates `true`. So in your first try, for example, `<expression>` is `if key.scan(/word/) then @entries[key] = value`. btw, since `@entries[key] == value` before the expression is evaluated, the `then` part isn't doing anything. Also, `scan` is not the best here; `key =~ /word/` is sufficient. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.)  In your second attempt,  you are attempting to match on the string "word_or_prefix", which probably is not what you intended.

Comment: Suppose we added `@d.add('tiff' => "minor dispute")` to the test. Should that key-value pair be included in the hash returned?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Cary Swoveland...as always your ability to break things down in to digestible chunks is appreciated! Now as for your 'suppose' my answer would be no, it shouldn't add that. Would my current code include 'tiff' if it came across it -  the prefix it is looking for is 'fi' in the test... would the regex still pick up a 'if' and add it ????

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have said, "@d.add('infinity' => "really big")`. As to what to do that, watch for an edit by @pguardiario.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Makes more sense. Well in the case of 'infinity' then no, it should't be included. I only want it to pick up the prefix's. So how would I refractor it so it would just look at the first x letters of the key, x being the exact length of the prefix? something like `pf = word.length` and then `if key[0..pf] =~ /word/` ? I know that code is probably wrong but is the logic correct?

Comment: You can add a "beginning of string" anchor `^` to the regex, making it `/^#{word}/` or use the method [String#begin_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) instead of a regex. If you don't care about case, write `key[/#{word}/i]` or `key.downcase.start_with?(word)`.

Comment: I got my case backward with `start_with?` (assuming the dictionary is all lower case): `key.start_with?(word.downcase)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for:

```
@entries.select{|key, value| key[/#{word}/] }
```

Comment: Sweet!! Way simpler than I thought it would be! Thanks!

Comment: But if you could...just so I better understand where I went wrong... why was my code returning the entire hash?

Comment: Because the condition inside the select block was always truthy

Comment: You might want to address the "Suppose..." comment I left above.